# Change package installation path at source explorer's level

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

Is it possible to change path of a `nuget` package at `Source Explorer's` level? Suppose, we want to install newest `Bootstrap` package for your `ASP.NET MVC5` project using `nuget`.
In default it installs its `CSS` files in `~/Content/` folder. What if I would like the files to be inside `~/Content/Libs/`?
Of course I can move them manually, but I would like to keep a possibility of updating the libraries via `nuget`.

Comment: This is not supported. Content files are added to the directory specified by the NuGet package.

Comment: Plz, convert your comment into an answer. I will mark it as a solution.